# MODx Parse Error on home page

Tags: parsing, caching, modx, modx-evolution

I've been having this error over lot of modx evolution 1.0.5 installations (I allways use 1&1 servers, in Linux version) It fails to load the home page (not any other pages) it seems that every time I clean the cache, via the manager or via API code, it creates again this file in the cache:
**docid_1.pageCache.php**

But the thing is that even if the folder cache and all the files inside are set to 777 permissions when it creates files for caching they have any permission set and that's the thing causing this error.

Anybody has had this error? I've been searching in MODX forums but didn't find anybody worried about this, but still I can see it's something happening a lot since when I search on google this error, I don't find forum posts discussing this but instead lots of modx frontend pages showing this error at their home pages.

Maybe it's a problem with 1&1 PHP configuration.

I'm really worried about this cose it has happen some times when I client calls me "über mad" complaining about his home page showing this error.

I've seen that new 1.06 version has some fix on the pagecache parser but I don't know if it's related to my problem.

Here's the error page:

> « MODx Parse Error »
>
> MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the
>   requested resource: « PHP Parse Error »
>
> ```
> PHP error debug   Error: file(assets/cache/docid_1.pageCache.php) [function.file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
> Error type/ Nr.: Warning - 2
> File: /homepages/3/d405318697/htdocs/t3st/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php
> Line: 413
> Line 413 source: $flContent= implode("", file($cacheFile));
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The cheeky answer? - "upgrade" Evolution is dead.

A more helpful answer, check the modx system settings,  in Revolution you can tell modx what permissions to attempt to set on files, my guess is that maybe you have inadvertently set these to 000 if that's what you mean by this: "they have any permission set"

If that does not work/you get desperate, disable all caching and test or if possible [still not familiar with evo] set that resource to not be cached.

Though something odd is going on, please confirm; the index page will be cached but with no permissions i.e. 000, subsequent pages will be cached but do have correct permissions set? i.e. 666 [or 644/whatever]

Comment: Hey, yes, I see the point of upgrading to revo but when I tried it I found the backend too "ajaxy" and way too slow. The permisions in the general website are set to 0644 and it's working fine with some snippets that create files (img thumbnails for example). I updated to MODX 1.0.6 and seems that it works fine with a website I check everyday, since this error is not happening allways, just sometimes.

Comment: yes - the new backend is pretty fat, there are a couple of things you can do though, there are caching options for the manager scripts & css as well as some interface options [like turning off the resource browser refreshing]

Comment: I checked again today, a client called me asking about the same problem. I checked and it just happens on the cache for the item with id "1" wich usually is the home page. There were other cached files and all of them where created with the right permisions but not the home one, so the error is caused because the file don't even have the permision for reading it. My workaround has been as you told the easiest one, just disabling the cache for that page, but still I feel I would like to have a more clarifing idea of what's going on

Comment: Do both these websites happen to be on the same server? & what is the size of the cache file? i.e. is there actually anything written to it?

Comment: Yes, it's the same website, at the same server. And the file it's normal, with content on it, the only difference is that the home page one has no permissions to read, write, or execute.

Comment: Start looking at your database a little bit - I have seen a couple of threads that indicate an overloaded [or mis-configured] database can cause issues with the cache.